# Use a regex pattern to search a file and count occurances

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to search the DNS Bind querylog file ( domain requests for DNS) on Linux (raspberry pi)  with a pattern to pull out the domains and then tally up the occurances of each domain

The command below is what I have come up with to get the top 10 domains in the file.

```
egrep -o 'query:\s(.*?)\s' querylog > domainlist.txt && sort domainlist.txt | uniq --count | sort -r -n | head -n 10
```

However, I'm pretty sure this can be done is one statement but I don't know how. Can someone suggest how?

Comment: Please add some example lines so we have something to test

Comment: Are you simply asking how to omit the intermediate file? so `... > domainlist.txt && sort domainlist.txt | uniq ... ` becomes `... | sort | uniq ...`

Comment: Yes. that's exactly it. thx